# Get source/upstream connection's processor name in nifi

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

I want to monitor the flowfiles in Nifi from business perspective.

So I have added executescript processor using python script which creates the message and pushes the same in elasticsearch after each processor.

I want the parent processor name or id of this executescript processor so that I will keep appending in the flowfile which will allow to know through which stages/processors this flow file is passed through and I can monitor it in ELK.

Comment: NiFi derives from the Flow Based Programming paradigm where each component is a "black box" that is intentionally not aware of predecessor or successor components. I would caution that trying to determine these component identities is unsupported and brittle if possible programmatically, and definitely an anti-pattern. You should re-evaluate the monitoring plan you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to monitor FlowFiles is to use the Provenance logs. You can also export those logs to ELK using another NiFi instance and S2S.

Anyway, if you want to get the processor's name of a connection's source/destination using the REST API you can get it when you browse a process group's connections.
Example:

```
/nifi-api/process-groups/{processGroupId}/connections/
```

You'll get an array of connections. In the connection object, you will get the name of the source in the path `component/source/name`. The same goes for destination.

EDIT:

To use provenance logs you need to do as follows:

1. Send provenance logs to another NiFi instance(it is restricted to NiFi since it uses S2S).
2. Parse the logs in this NiFi instance
3. Send the logs to ElasticSearch using the `PutElasticSearch5` processor.

It works the best and will help you monitor the FlowFiles the best :)

Comment: Is there a way to fetch it from session (session.get()) object which I get in python script?. I will explore S2S option.

Comment: you can't get it from the `ProcessSession` nor from `ProcessContext`... As I said, the best way to monitor FlowFiles is to use the Provenance Logs. You can use `SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask` to transfer the provenance logs to the other instance. It's easy too! You just need to enable site to site protocol in the destination instance(with `nifi.properties`)

Comment: I tried S2S. There I am unsure what will be Input Port name as I am not sending this to another nifi instance but sending it to elasticsearch

Comment: It throws Error running task SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask[id=bf4858b6-0169-1000-b06f-640d8cba6a3e] due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to send Provenance Events to destination due to IOException:response code 405:Method Not Allowed with explanation: null

Comment: I was able to capture the data through S2S but it captures all the events, In the actual core dataflow my flow files have appid  as an attribute  So I added a routeonattribute processor and and checked for condition where appid is notnull but now I don't get any of the message

Comment: I have enabled S2SReportingTask on monitoring nifi instance

Comment: The event doesn't contain the actual content of the FlowFile.. It would make each event too big and can make it grow to Gibibytes of data.. It contains a reference to the content claim. You can, however, configure the reporting task to work in a certain process group or on specific processors using `Component ID to Include` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. One more doubt. I have used routeOncontent to check if flow file content contains "name" as json key? Tried ${previousAttributes.name:notNull()} but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190823/discussion-between-ben-yaakobi-and-happy).